# Openstack: No Networking node in Mirantis fuel dashboard

Tags: openstack

I am new to openstack and started my first deployment of openstack through Mirantis Fuel 9.0. I could not find any Network node in the fuel dashboard. If there is no network node where will be the L3 agent and dhcp agent will run. Could you kindly help me to get clarify on this one [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gixHC.jpg) or let me know if i am missing anything here ?

Answer (score 0):

The network node is part of the Controller role in Fuel. All the neutron agents run there.